# Complete the circular contour edge when using canny edge detection and the contour is not occluded

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

I want to binarize the bone areas (make the bones areas be 255, and the other areas be 0)
but the gray level distribution is not simple enough(it's brighter in the lower half part) to just find a value and threshold it. So I think if I can detect its complete contours and fill the spaces inside these contours may be an easier way.

Original image:

[image]

After applying canny edge detection:

[image]

I've tried to find a reasonable way to to got these contours of bones occluded but failed. Please give me advice if any. Thank you very much.

I also need to deal with the issues that if there are two bones overlapping together.
(I apologize i didn't mention this in the very first place..)

I'm considering how can i separate a pair of bones overlapping together:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo52L.png

Comment: You'd better initiate a new post on your second question of separating the overlapping. It looks like a different one from your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Active Contours (snakes)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model)

It computes "fuzzy" edges by considering both local gradient, and the overall "smoothness"
(this description isn't very accurate, It's just to understand the concept)

I tried in several similar cases and got good results.

Comment: This method is not very familiar for me though I'll check this out.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The low [Contrast to Noise Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast-to-noise_ratio) of your raw image makes the object extraction challenge since the threshold setting may not be robust to every image. Yet I tried to extract the bones in your current figure. Two tricks are applied in my processing:(1) non-linear transform of your image to enhance the bones with low intensity compared with the background; (2) zero padding on the border of your image at the possible bone regions after the canny edge detector is applied. See my code below:

```
I=rgb2gray(I);

I=double(I);
I=I.^0.6;  % non linear transform before canny edge detector
BW=edge(I,'canny');

 %%% padding at the possible bone regions
BW(1,BW(2,:)==1)=1;
BW(end,BW(end-1,:)==1)=1;
BW(BW(:,2)==1,1)=1;
BW(BW(:,end-1)==1,end)=1;

%%% padding in order to fill in the bone boundaries
bw2=imfill(padarray(BW,size(BW),'symmetric'),'holes');
bw2=bw2(size(bw,1)+(1:size(bw,1)),size(bw,2)+(1:size(bw,2)));

bw2=bwareaopen(bw2,200); % remove the too small regions
MASK=I>10;  % remove the background with very low intensity
figure,imshow(bw2.*MASK)
```

The result:

[image]

Everything looks good except one bone boundary is a little bit messy.